# Is it possible in Bing Maps v8 to display a tile layer underneath the street/highway lines of an aerial map (labels on)?

Tags: bing-maps

The following is adapted from [Bing Maps V8 interactive SDK](https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk#tileLayerQuadKey+JS):

```
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
    credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key',
    center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(25, -90),
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.aerial
});

// Custom tiles of Hurricane Katrina for zoom level 1-10
var katrinaTileSource = new Microsoft.Maps.TileSource({
    uriConstructor: 'https://bingmapsisdk.blob.core.windows.net/katrinatiles/{quadkey}.png',
    bounds: Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromEdges(35.176, -101.065, 14.01, -80.538)
});
var katrinaTileLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.TileLayer({
    mercator: katrinaTileSource,
    zIndex: 1000
});
map.layers.insert(katrinaTileLayer);
```

The tile layer is displayed underneath the text labels, but not the highways/streets/territory boundaries (when labels are turned on). I have tried adjusting the zIndex, but it seems like these lines are on the same layer as the aerial map itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the road lines are rendered on the base map tiles on the server side with the rest of the map background. If you try different zIndex values you will find that you can put the tile layer above or below the base map tiles, but not between the road lines and the rest of the map background.